# Vertical scrollview of gridview not working properly android

Tags: android, gridview, scrollview

here is my xml code in android app. I need horizontal scroll in this layout but using this my gridview's vertical layout is not working properly.When i use this code it scrolls horizontally but it does not allow gridview's vertical scroll to work proper. How can i fix this??? i have changed my code to this now but my horizontal scroll does not work..vertical scroll is fine now in gridview

```
  <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
  <ScrollView
   android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

       />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/doc"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/sbmt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/report" />

  </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
  <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/timeslot" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/appoint" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/waiting" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/protocol" />
     </LinearLayout>
     <LinearLayout

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
     >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="900dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

</ListView>

  </LinearLayout>
   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="@string/welcome"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: try this `android:scrollbars="horizontal|vertical"` this will set scrollbars for both direction

Comment: no still same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use listview inside scrollview because Listview so have inbuild scrolling capabilities. Encapsulate it in any other layout like LinearLayout or RelativeLayout

Use like this...

```
   <LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
   >

      <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:text="welcome"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

      <HorizontalScrollView 
          android:id="@+id/hori_scroll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          >
      <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
         >
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="22dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="date"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
       <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

       />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="doc"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="sbmt" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="report" />

  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="timeslot" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="appoint" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="waiting" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="protocol" />
     </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

</ListView>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` and make it root/container layout. Replace `ScrollView` with `RelativeLayout`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <RelativeLayout
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="22dp" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/date"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                   <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"

                   />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/doc"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/sbmt" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                    android:text="@string/report" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/timeslot" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/appoint" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView7"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/waiting" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:text="@string/protocol" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView1"
                android:layout_width="900dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp" >

            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="96dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
            android:text="@string/welcome"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```